# ASP CrytographicException: Access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I’m trying to run a sample from an Azure SDK winch communicates with the Azure MFA service.  The sample compiles and runs in visual studio but once I deploy it to IIS I get the error below:

> Access is denied.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access is denied.
```

I suspect it’s related to a certificate that is needed to authenticate to the Azure service but not sure how to troubleshoot as I’m not a developer by trade.   The certificate is in the same location as the ASP app and it’s referenced correctly in the code.  Again, the code works through Visual Studio.

Stack Trace:

```
[CryptographicException: Access is denied.
]
   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr) +41
   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._QueryCertFileType(String fileName) +0
   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) +125
   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) +141
   pf_auth.send_message(String target, String message, String cert_file_path, String& body) +221
   pf_auth.pf_authenticate_internal(PfAuthParams pfAuthParams, Boolean asynchronous, String& otp, Int32& call_status, Int32& error_id) +744
   MFADemo.example.btnTest_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1602
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +11754953
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +150
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3619
```

Comment: Check your application has Read permissions on the certificate file you're loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are better off uploading the cert to your application in Azure Management portal in the Configure tab:

[image]

And then in the code your Cert store location should be "CurrentUser" instead of "LocalMachine" for it to work in Azure...

We had multiple issues with reading certificates from file system in Azure and ended up uploading it to he Azure website and reading it from the store...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The server is running on-premises.  Here is how I'm loading the .p12 cert:,
`String cert_file_path = ""C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\cert_key.p12";`,
`X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate2(cert_file_path, CERT_PASSWORD, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
    request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);`